# How to render pdf page into svg

Tags: html, svg, canvas, pdf.js

In the example of helloworld, pdf page was rendering into canvas. I'm wondering that how to render pdf page into svg?

```
// Hello World
// http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/
var scale = 1.5;
var viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale, });

var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.height = viewport.height;
canvas.width = viewport.width;

var renderContext = {
  canvasContext: context,
  viewport: viewport
};
page.render(renderContext);

// ...
```